# How to install the most stable & latest nvidia driver in 12.04?

Tags: nvidia, ppa

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7.

After completing the Software Update process, I thought that my nVidia drivers also would have been updated, but after restarting the system and checking the version, it still was showing as version 173.14.35.  I have nvidia geforce 7025 / 630a integrated in my ASUS motherboard

Can someone tell me how can I update my drivers with the most latest and stable release?

Also when searching a lot I went through couple of pages which showed something like PPA. Can someone please explain me what is a PPA?

Comment: Regarding PPA's: there are several topics on AU regarding PPA's. Please have a look around this site.http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I don't know your graphics card model, so my answer is based on assumption.**

Its looks like your graphics card is old and use `legacy 173` driver from nvidia.

If so, for your graphics card, there was no development done from nivida in terms of version.
So whatever you have is the best and latest driver. If you forcefully install new drivers it will cause lag/crash to your system.

A ppa is a package bundle provided by 3rd party (meaning any other than Ubuntu official). 
Adding a ppa and installing an app/driver from it means you will be receiving updates for them when the ppa owner updates a page.

Basically ppa s are for easy install and update process.

See more details from this discussion [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/35775)

-- **Update** --

If you want stable an updated driver. Please use `x-swat` ppa. This team provide latest & stable drivers for ubuntu. Issue the following commands,

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Comment: Oops :)  Sorry ... 

I have nvidia geforce 7025 / 630a integrated in my ASUS motherboard...

Comment: Yes. Then 173 driver is the latest for your graphics card in linux

Comment: Are you sure sir..??

Because when I visited nvidia's site :

http://www.nvidia.in/object/linux-display-amd64-295.59-driver-in.html

Under the supported products tab my gfx (geforce 7025 / nforce 630a) was given...

Comment: You can try with it or See the updated answer. But I will say if you are not having problem with 173. Stick with it.

Comment: Hello Sir..

Even after trying your terminal commands that you posted ... nVidia X server settings still showing version 173...

I don't get it..I mean I updated to the latest version but still somehow I am getting that same driver ...

I have manually downloaded the beta version of nvidia driver from the official site 
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22.run ...Should I install it..??

Its version 304.22 beta... 

If YES.. then how can I install it...??

PLease sir... reply ASAP ... :)

thank you ... :)

Comment: If you're going to try the drivers downloaded from NVIDIA, I'd recommend the stable 295.59 ahead of the beta 304.22. But the method of running is the same. `chmod +x NVIVIA-Linux-X86_64-304.22.run` (or ...295.59.run) then `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-X86_64-304.22.run`. As I recall, if it doesn't detect a supported device it won't install.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding: `most latest and stable release`

Open `dash` with the super key.

Start typing `addi`

It will show an icon with `additional drivers` underneath. Check what drivers it shows and pick one that works best.

Example:

[image]

Installing drivers with a PPA tends to be bleeding edge and unstable versions or give support to abandoned drivers or old cards etc. Keep away from those if you are not 100% sure how to fix problems that arise from those drivers.

Comment: Sir.. I have already installed them from additional drivers option..

I selected the NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (version 173)

There are other options also :

NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver  (post release version)(version 173 updates)

I chose the 1st one coz the recommended one which showed current version was buggy & stopped compiz from working...

Comment: Sir can u tell me how did u embedded that image into this site ..

Because I also want to add image to show which driver from additional drivers section I have chosen ...

Comment: @sud_the_devil there is a icon where you can upload an image when asking and when answering at the icon bar atop of the text input.

Comment: and how does that thing you do with an ATI Driver apply to an nvidia problem?

Comment: @henning it does since the actions are the same. He will get the nVidia driver and I get the AMD one.

Comment: hmm, ok i see and partly agree, but only for simple cases. in complex cases, if the card is a special one that is hardly supported, it's different.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT DELETED: it's not a good idea to install these manually, use the instructions below that others have given because you will run into an issue with the DKMS added Kernel support in 304.22 and it will break your Ubuntu installation if you attempt to revert back to your previous installation of the Nvidia drivers.  It's very complex to fix a bad install of these so I no longer recommend doing it this way.

Comment: Hello Sir..

Even after trying the terminal commands that posted below...

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current

My  nVidia X server settings still showing me version 173...

I don't get it..I mean I updated to the latest version but still somehow I am getting that same driver ...

I have manually downloaded the beta version of nvidia driver from the official site 
NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.22.run ...Should I install it..??



If YES.. then how can I install it...??

PLease sir... reply ASAP ... :)

Comment: Thank You for the answer sir...

But I cannot get past the 4th step where I have to open the TTY terminal.. After pressing the ALT + CTRL + F1 nothing happens on the screen ...

I have a 64 bit UBUNTU ...so the file name of the driver name was a bit different but I got that one right...

Just that TTY terminal problem is not getting solved ...

Comment: @sud_the_devil I HIGHLY RECOMMEND THAT YOU USE THE INSTRUCTIONS BELOW THAT OTHERS HAVE SUGGESTED. USE THE OFFICIAL UBUNTU INSTALLER "ADDITIONAL DRIVERS" AND SELECT THE MOST RECENT NVIDIA DRIVERS OR THE ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates REPOSITORY SEE INSTRUCTIONS THAT OTHERS HAVE POSTED.

Comment: yes sir I have followed the instructiob given by @Web-E