# Error while installing nVidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, proprietary

I'm trying to install the latest (as of 27/09/2012) nVidia drivers for my GTX 660 through the Additional Drivers tab in System Settings. It ends up aborting, producing a log that says something about XorgDriverHandler not being installed. What do I do to fix it? I've tried to reinstall it by purging it but to no avail.

Comment: can i have the output of: nvidia-settings --version

Comment: Kindly see below.

Answer (score 2):

Check your current version. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
nvidia-settings --version
```

To install nVidia Linux Display Driver under Ubuntu 11.10/12.04, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

My advice, always choose stable release.

Refer [**this post**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169302/how-to-install-the-most-stable-latest-nvidia-driver-in-12-04)

[**Launchpad**](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers)

**My Nvidia Driver Version**

[image]

Comment: Hi. I get the exact same output as you do when I type in the version command. I get the same error as before, with the jockey log. If I try to install through the GUI, it says that "This driver was just disabled, but is still in use.". What gives?

Comment: What version are you using right now? You can set your nvidia by launch Nvidia X server from dash

Comment: Unsure what you mean, but I can see 1.11.3 Server Vendor Version, 1.28 NV-CONTROL version and the 304.51 NVIDIA Driver version.